# subset and replace a character in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
YC<-c(".PT" ,  ".PG",   ".PG",   ".PG",   ".PA" ,   ".PA",   ".PA",   ".PA")
```

I want to transform `YC` to a dataframe and remove the dot it, this is what I am trying, but does not work

```
as.data.frame(factor(YC, unique(YC)))[,1]<-
  sub(pattern="^.", replacement="", x=as.data.frame(factor(YC, unique(YC)))[,1])
```

Output:

```
1    PT
2    PG
3    PA
```

Comment: "\\." since "." is a metacharacter

Comment: your output is not having "PA"  why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df = data.frame(unique(YC))

df$unique.YC. = gsub(pattern = "^.", x = df$unique.YC., replacement = "", perl = T)
df
    # unique.YC.
    # 1         PT
    # 2         PG
    # 3         PA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`.  As `.` is a metacharacter which means any other character, we can either escape (`\\`), place it in a square bracket (`[.]`) or specify the `fixed = TRUE` argument to match it and replace it with `""`.

```
data.frame(YC=sub(".", "", YC, fixed = TRUE))
```